# Ubuntu 20.04 PPC VM kubelet snap not working

Tags: powerpc

Running an Ubuntu 20.04 PPC VM on a Blackbird POWER9 host with Fedora 35 PPC as its host OS.

Trying to get a test Kubernetes cluster going on VMs, using Ubuntu 20.04 PPC as the VM OS. So this is inside the Ubuntu 20.04 VM.

While installing Kubernetes tools, I found that kubelet needs to be installed via a snap, and `snap install kubectl --classic` seemed to work and claimed to have installed it, but `kubeadm init` failed complaining about kubectl. `systemctl status kubectl` can't find the kubelet.service.

I'll be *super* surprised if anyone else has ever tried this, but I'm hoping for advice from people who understand kubernetes tools better than I do.

Answer (score 0):

not a direct answer for the snap issue, but confirmed I was getting the same with the snap, so reverted to tried and true kubernetes.io repo:

```
kver="1.24.2-00"
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add
echo "deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
sudo apt-get update

for k in kubelet kubeadm kubectl; do sudo apt-get install -y ${k}=$kver; done
sudo apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl
```